# .coveragerc unable to locate files I want omitted

Tags: python, pytest, coverage.py, pytest-cov

I am using `tox` to automatically run my tests using `pytest` and `pytest-cov` plugin. However, I'm getting coverage reports for the files I omitted in `.coveragerc`:

```
(env) alex@smartalex-pc:~/.repos/codelib/github/project$ tox

[...]

../../../tests/test_module1.py::test_func PASSED  [  3%]

[...]

../../../tests/test_module2.py::test_func PASSED  [100%]

----------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.6.7-final-0 -----------
Name                                                                                                   Stmts   Miss  Cover
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/home/alex/.repos/codelib/github/project/.tox/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/package/__init__.py             0      0   100%
/home/alex/.repos/codelib/github/project/.tox/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/package/__main__.py             2      2     0%
/home/alex/.repos/codelib/github/project/.tox/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/package/application.py         40      0   100%
/home/alex/.repos/codelib/github/project/.tox/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/package/core.py                73      0   100%
/home/alex/.repos/codelib/github/project/.tox/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/package/user_interface.py      45      0   100%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                                                                                        160      2    99%
```

It seems that `tox` does not use my `.coveragerc`. I tried to explicitly specify the config file with `--cov-config={toxinidir}/.coveragerc`, but I get the same result again.

Simplified project structure:

```
package/
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
    application.py
    core.py
    user_interface.py
tests/
    test_module1.py
    test_module2.py
.coveragerc
pytest.ini
setup.py
tox.ini
```

This is my `tox.ini`:

```
[tox]
envlist = py36

[testenv]
changedir = {envtmpdir}
deps = 
    trio
    -r dev-requirements.txt
commands =
    pytest -v {toxinidir}/tests --cov=package --cov-config={toxinidir}/.coveragerc
```

This is my `.coveragerc`:

```
[run]
omit =
    package/__main__.py
    package/__init__.py
```

This is my `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
trio_mode = true
```

I think this is enough but let me know if you need more output/information.

How can I overcome the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change .coveragerc to:

```
[run]
omit =
    */package/__main__.py
    */package/__init__.py
```

Comment: That didn't quite work. I'm not getting full coverage (which I do when I run `pytest -v tests --cov=package`) for my modules, and I also get a bunch of "internals" covered (like `env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/nose.py                         37     25    32%`)

Comment: I did omit them (`__main__.py` and `__init__.py`), and I specified the package that I want covered with `--cov=package`.

Comment: Try add to ommit `*.tox*` and `*env/*` and `*__main__.py` and `*__init__.py`

Comment: hmm, adding the glob in front of filenames actually kind of worked, however isn't exactly the solution I was hoping for. It omits all files whereas I was looking to omit just two particular files.

Comment: In order to be more specific you can prefix them with the package `*package/__main__.py` and `*package/__init__.py`. Be aware that the absolute path will be different when running with tox compared with when you running with pytest. If you want to work in both cases you still need to have `*` in the path.

Comment: okay, I'll give you an upvote for now and if no one comes up with a better solution, I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks for your help!

Comment: btw I think you should narrow down your answer to just the last part (chaning `.coveragerc`)

Comment: Please change `*package` to `*/package`, since the latter is more explicit about specifying the path. Also, updating `pytest.ini` wasn't necessary, so I would delete that part of the answer, too.