# Django & coverage - .coveragerc omit not working

Tags: django, coverage.py, django-unittest

I have a Django project with multiple applications. In one application, I have a library already tested using unittest + coverage.
When I run the test of the django project, I would like to omit this folder.

My project architecture is :

```
project/
├── application1/
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── ...
│   └── my_lib/ << The lib I want to omit
│       ├── tests.py
│       ├── script.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── ...
├── application2/
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── ...
├── application3/
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── ...
├── .coveragerc
├── runtest.bat
├── manage.py
└── ...
```

**runtest.bat** is :

```
CALL activate ./venv
coverage erase
coverage run manage.py test
coverage html
PAUSE
```

Based on several tutorials and SO questions, I've tried several **.coveragerc** files but none of them properly skipped the library. Testing it creates a fail because it tries to load with the incorrect relative path.

**.coveragerc** is :

```
[run]
omit =
    */application1/my_lib/*
    
[report]

exclude_lines =
    if __name__ == .__main__.:
show_missing = True
```

I also tried :

```
[run]
source = .
omit =
    /application1/my_lib/*
```

```
[run]
source = project/*
omit =
    */application1/my_lib/*
```

```
[run]
source = .
omit =
    */application1/my_lib/*
```

Do you have any clue what am I doing wrong ?

For information :

- Django version is 2.2.5
- Coverage version is 4.5.4
- Python version is 3.7

Few sources :

- [Django Coverage](https://adamj.eu/tech/2019/04/30/getting-a-django-application-to-100-percent-coverage/)
- [Coverage Documentation](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.3.4/config.html#paths)
- [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536483/coveragerc-unable-to-locate-files-i-want-omitted)

Thanks in advance

---

#### EDIT 1:

Just as a background. **my_lib** is mainly a file containing a class. This code is just embedded in the application to be used "like" a standard library.

In *application1/views.py*, I simply have a `from . import my_lib`.

In *application1/my_lib/__init__.py*, I have `from .script import MyClass`

The objective is simply to be able then to use in my view with  `my_lib.MyClass.do_something()`

Now the reason why I would like to exclude this "library" from the coverage is because this was developped out of the application. It has his own unittest in *applications1/my_lib/tests/py* starting with `from script import MyClass`.

When I run the coverage in the root of the project, Python cannot find *script.py* in the root of the project so it triggers the error

> File "path_to/project/application1/my_lib/tests.py", line 3
>
> from script import MyClass
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named script.

In the worst case scenario, I could put this library to *site-packages* of my virtual environment bu I would like to avoid it (there will be probably multiple similar **my_lib** with at most 1 per application)

---

#### EDIT 2:

As a temporary solution, I simply renamed *application1/my_lib/tests.py* by *application1/my_lib/script_tests.py*. There is no file starting by **test** so the coverage does not care about this folder anymore.

The other alternative to run the test at the same time as the project required quite a lot of updates due to relative path used to several files

Comment: Could you try:
```ini
[run]
omit =
    application1/my_lib/*
```
Without leading start and without `source`.
It should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your time and proposal. Unfortunately, I still have the error `from my_lib import Foo ModuleNotFoundError: No module named my_lib` I have no clue if there is a way to ensure that the config file is properly considered

Comment: Your problem is not that the file isn't omitted from the test coverage, It's that you have an import problem. omiting it from the coverage won't make it go away.

Comment: Can you show the full error report? What is causing that import error?

Comment: I've added a part in the question to explain more in details the error. The idea behind omitting the folder is to avoid testing *tests.py* in my_lib leading to this import error